# set a:active style to links which have a name value?

Tags: html, css

When you click a link, a:active style of the clicked link is being applied. So when I've got a link which gets called and activated from the url using its name like whats shown below, why doesn't my code work?

```css
.box{
   display:block;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background:gray;
   margin:20px 0px;
}
a{
   -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
   -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
}
a:active{
   background:orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <a href="#user">user</a>    
    <a class="box" name="user">userbox</a>
</body>
```

I want it to call a:active css for userbox when userbox is called from the url.
Is my code invalid or not an option for these kind of situations?

Comment: CSS cannot track that, you cannot highlight the link if the relevant box is in an active state, for that you will need jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the pseudo-class you want is `:focus`. `:active` is applied while a link is being clicked.

-EDIT-

Of the browsers I tested, only Internet Explorer 11 focused the anchor when the URL was updated to include #user. You can use JavaScript to set a class as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function () {
  var activeElement = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substring(1));
  if (activeElement) {
    activeElement.className = 'active';
  }
});
```

This would require using the following CSS:

```
.active {
  color: orange;
}
```

And this assumes using `id="user"` instead of `name="user"` which both behave the same with regard to the URL hash.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to call a:active css for userbox when userbox is called from the url. my code is invalid or it's not an option for this kinda situations?

You can't. `:active` means "While being clicked on or otherwise activated". It *does not* mean "Having an `href` attribute that resolves to the current URI".

Use some other mechanism, such as adding a class to the element in the HTML.

Comment: There isn't one. Use some other mechanism, such as adding a class to the element in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

We can hack it, we have the technology.
In all seriousness you should use classes and Javascript for this solution, but I put a bit too much of my lunch time into this to just throw it away.

http://jsfiddle.net/DF4VG/

CSS:

```
#label {
    display: block;
}

#label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}

#user {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#user:focus {
    background: orange;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="">
    <label id="label" for="user">User</label>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <p>There is some content in here</p>
            <p>And some more</p>
            <p>And so forth</p>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="user" value="" readonly>
    </div>
</form>
```